# How to check array values using IN operator?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-in

I have a table where each cell in columns has an array list.

```
          COL1              COL2 
row1: ('hi','hello')    ('hi','hello')
row2: ('hihi','below')    ('pi','by')
```

I am trying to use an in operator on such data but my query is not returning anything.

```
Query: select * from table where col1 in ('hi')
```

Also, if I have another table (table2) that looks like this:

```
col3
____
'hi'
'bye'
'guy'
```

and I want to use the same concept where I'll be checking if `'hi','bye','guy'` from `col3` exists in `col1` `row1`

```
My Query: select * from table2 where col3 in (select col1 from table1);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "an array within a cell" in databases. Each cell contains a single piece of data.

Comment: If you are using a database that has a concept of arrays, it's non-standard. So please do as the [tag:sql] tag already asked you to do and add a tag identifying which database product you're actually working with.

Comment: `in` works on a *relational set of rows* - it does not parse strings. You should tag the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: If this is postgresql have a look at [array functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the "inside" one, the second one is the group of values.

You are comparing col1 (a tuple of 2 values) to a unique value:

I think that could help you: col1[0] -> gets the first value

```
select * from table where col1[0] in ('hi')
```

Whether you want to compare both, you can use:

```
select * from table where col1[0] in ('hi') or col1[1] in ('hi')
```

Comment: Can you please look at my updated question? is my 2nd query valid?

Comment: @LalaLand Yes, I suppose so! Col3 has unique values and 'select col1 from table1' will return a list of tuples.